# C # Excel Interop - adding the function / module to the worksheet from the string

Tags: c#, vba, excel-interop, worksheet

I need to add a some functionality to new worksheet creted in the excel workbook.
I have to **add a code** to the newly crated **worksheet** (worksheet's module), and add to it some VBA code from the string. I thin that I should create a new module that is assigned to the worksheet, but I don't know how.

I put below an example code with the function **AddCodeForWorksheet(Worksheet worksheet)** that should do the work:

```
using Common.Extensions;
using Common.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelOperations
{
  class PrepareExcelFile
  {
    string _worksheetShiftReport = "New Worksheet";

    private void AddCodeForWorksheet(Worksheet worksheet)
    {
        string vbaCode = 
    @"
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        Beep
    End Sub
    ";

        //this code produces an exception - Subscript out of range
        //
        //var worksheetModule = worksheet.Parent.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(worksheet.Name);
        //worksheetModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(vbaCode);

    }

    public void PrepareNewWorksheetForShiftReportUsingInterop(string fileName)
    {
        Application excel = null;
        Workbook workbook = null;
        Worksheet worksheet = null;
        try
        {
            excel = new Application
            {
                AutomationSecurity = MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable,
                Visible = false
            };

            workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

            try { worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[_worksheetShiftReport]; } catch { }
            worksheet?.Delete();

            worksheet = (Worksheet) workbook.Worksheets.Add(
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    workbook.Worksheets[workbook.Worksheets.Count], System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value
                );
            worksheet.Name = _worksheetShiftReport;

            AddCodeForWorksheet(worksheet);

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            excel?.Quit();

            if (worksheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
            if (workbook != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            if (excel != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
            excel = null;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @HenrikWilshusen I don't understand your question, could you explain it ?

Comment: I notice you releasing the one worksheet that you found, but the others (denoted by `x`) also need to be released.

Comment: @Enigmativity, There can be only one sheet with the specified name (that's why I used FirstOrDefault). Besides, the motice does not concern the subject of the question.

Comment: You need a reference to the Visual Basic for Application Extensibility library as well as programmatic access to the VB project being enabled *in the user interface* (part of the Trust Center) in order to add code to an Office document. Then I recommend you research using the VBA Extensibility object model (abbreviation: `VBE` - there are examples "out there".

Comment: @JerzyGebler - Yes, I know that only one can be selected but the fact that each is tested with `x => x.Name.Equals(_worksheetShiftReport)` means that until you find the right one all of the failed test `x` worksheets have had a managed reference created for them and you must release them too. In other words you can't use `workbook.Worksheets.OfType<Worksheet>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(_worksheetShiftReport))`

Comment: @Enigmativity, you are right, I'll redefine the code, thx.

Comment: @JerzyGebler - Yes, it's hard to get this kind of thing right. Every little thing that we get used to in nice neat managed code we have to think twice when doing COM interop.